# Restrict user cursor to date fields only in material angular control

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I have the form with the date picker control like this:

```
<mat-card class="mb-3">
    <mat-card-content>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" hideRequiredMarker>
            <mat-label>DOB+</mat-label>
            <input formControlName="dob" #ref matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
            <mat-hint>'DD-MM-YYYY'</mat-hint>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

How can I restrict the user from modifying the separators - so after editing `DD` the cursor  moves automatically to `MM`, after editing `MM` the cursor moves automatically to `YYYY` - not allowing the user to change the separator `-`.